# How can I get access to the Angular 2 http response body without converting it to string or json?

Tags: rest, angular, blob, httpresponse, angular2-http

I would like to copy a REST response into a blob but I am unable to do some because `blob()` and `arrayBuffer()` have not yet been implemented in the Response Object. The Response Body is a private variable.

```
...
return this.http.get(url, {params: params, headers: headers})
     .map(res => {   
        // can't access _body because it is private
        // no method appears to exist to get to the _body without modification             
        new Blob([res._body], {type: res.headers.get('Content-Type')});
     })
     .catch(this.log);
...
```

Is there a solution I can use until these methods get implemented?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There's a much simpler solution to accessing the body as a string which I haven't seen documented anywhere:

```
let body = res.text()
```

Comment: Wow! This solution actually allows npm to compile my TS too! Where did you even find this?

Comment: There was a lot of trial and error involved so I can't really recall I'm afraid.

Answer (score 10):

Addon to @StudioLE. You may use json() method to return data as json.

```
let body = res.json()
```

Comment: This is absolutely what should be used. On your `error` response, you could do `error.json()` and the actually returned data from the API will be available in template.

Comment: Dangit, I had forgot to use `.json()` lol thanks for this answer luckily I was only banging my head for a few minutes.

Answer (score 6):

Since I found this question while running into the same problem (and Angular's documentation is not updated as of today) you can now use:

```
let blob = new Blob([response.arrayBuffer()], { type: contentType });
```

Another workaround if you for some reason are on an old version of Angular 2 is:

```
let blob = new Blob([(<any> response)._body], { type: contentType });
```

Answer (score 2):

set the responseType of requestoptions. That will make the response.blob() method work.

```
let headers = this.getAuthorizationHeader();
headers.append("Accept", "application/octet-stream");
return this.http
    .get(url, new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob }))
    .map((res: Response): Blob => {
        return res.ok ? res.blob() : undefined;
    });
```

Comment: more info on the new features : http://restlet.com/company/blog/2016/08/29/whats-new-in-the-http-module-of-angular-2/, dont forget to use subscribe to exploit the result

Answer (score 1):

I can't see no other solutions before the following PR is merged:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7260

Whereas you have a compilation error, the field can be used at runtime...